# Full-Text Search with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the best way to use full-text search with EFCore

For now I have two approaches

Approach #1

```
 var entities = this.DbContext.Example
            .FromSql("fullText_Proc {0}, {1}", searchTermParameter, topParameter);

        return entities.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Here I'm forced to create a proc because FromSql ignores the WHERE clause.

Approach #1

Create a command and do the mapping manually

```
using (var command = this.DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT ... WHERE CONTAINS("Name", @p1)";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        var parameter = new SqlParameter("@p1",...);

        this.DbContext.Database.OpenConnection();

        using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (result.Read())
            {
               .... // Map entity
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used your second approach to fetch ranked results with CONTAINSTABLE which can't be achieved using FromSql for the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WHERE clause is working with FromSql, actually.
I spent enough time to realize problem was passing parameter.

This is how I have solved the problem.

```
  public IList<Example> QueryPhrase(string phrase)
    {
        phrase = $"FORMSOF(FREETEXT, \"{phrase}\")";

        var query = _dataContext.Example
            .FromSql(@"SELECT [Id]
                      ,[Sentence]                          
                    FROM [dbo].[Example]
                    WHERE CONTAINS(Sentence, @p0)", phrase)
            .AsNoTracking();

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: How would you define a  full-text index on column "Sentence" of entity "Example" with Entity Framework Core? I am trying to do something similar but I need the full-text index defined so that the code works.

Comment: I too am trying to do the same as @VMh, would like to know as well!

Comment: You don't do it with EF Core. It should be created on Sql server at first then you can query using Contains.